# How to create multiple files with different names and write to them in Python

Tags: python

I have a for loop in Python, and I want to create a new file for each iteration. I want each new file to have the name 'output.xyz', 'output1.xyz', 'output2.xyz' ...... ect. Here is my code, its throwing out no errors but it not writing any files

```
number_structures = 270
for i in range(number_structures):
    with open('FeCO5.xyz', 'r+') as inputfile:
        molecule = pd.read_table(inputfile, skiprows=2, delim_whitespace=True,
                                 names=['atom', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
        
#Do something with FeC05.xyz number_structures amount of times....
      
           
        with open('output{}.xyz'.format(i), 'ab') as f:
            f.write('atom', 'x', 'y', 'z')
```

Comment: This is incorrect:

`number_structures = 270
for i in number_structures:`

Do you mean:
`for i in range(number_structures)` ?

Comment: Yes, I meant in range(number_structures)

Comment: This line is also incorrect:

`f.write('atom', 'x', 'y', 'z')` write takes only one argument, you gave 4

Comment: How do I change this to only give one argument?

Comment: What do you want to write in the file?

Comment: I'm trying to write an .xyz file. The first column is the symbol of the atom (eg. C), the second column is the x-coordinate, third column is the y-coordinate and fourth column is the z-coordinate.

Comment: I think I have it working now actually, thanks for your help in identifying my mistakes!

Comment: What will the file format be? CSV, txt or something else?

Comment: Great, i will add it as answer, please accept it, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your following lines must be amended:

```
number_structures = 270 
for i in number_structures:
```

must become:

```
number_structures = 270
for i in range(number_structures):
```

Also:

```
f.write('atom', 'x', 'y', 'z')
```

is not correct, as write takes only one argument, but you gave 4